# marker pin recreate on custom marker when user filter the marker then zoom in /out (Please Go through the below Description)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps, apple-maps, react-native-map-clustering

At first, render everything works fine, but as soon as a user tries to filter  marker through rest api after this step user zoom out or zoom in a map  default marker pin generate on custom marker

dependence:-  [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps)

check the recording video:-
[Video Link](https://www.veed.io/view/936a2d42-e71a-4a15-a082-eafd4388a24b)

[image: image of error]

```js
      <MapView
        ref={mapRef}
        rotateEnabled={false}
        shouldRasterizeIOS
        mapType="standard"
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={INITIAL_REGION}
        
      >
        {data &&
          data?.map(item => (
            <CustomMarker
              item={item}
              key={item?.id}
              setSelectedMarkerId={(row: any) => {
                mapRef?.current?.animateToRegion(
                  {
                    latitude: Number(row?.lat),
                    longitude: Number(row?.long),
                    latitudeDelta: 0.002,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.002,
                  },
                  1000,
                );
              }}
              coordinate={{
                latitude: Number(item?.lat),
                longitude: Number(item?.long),
              }}
            />
          ))}
      </MapView>
```

here is my custom Marker Code:-

```
const CustomMarker = ({ item, setSelectedMarkerId, setIsMarkerDetailShow , coordinate   }) => {
    const [tracksViewChanges, setTracksViewChanges] = useState(true);
 
    
  return (
    <Marker
    tracksViewChanges={tracksViewChanges}
      coordinate={coordinate}
      onPress={() => {
        setSelectedMarkerId(item);
        // setIsMarkerDetailShow(true);
      }}
      >
   <View>
   {item?.abribois ? (
        <Image
          source={require('src/assets/images/greenMarker.png')}
          style={{
            height: 30,
            width: 30,
            resizeMode: 'contain',
          }}
          onLoadEnd={() => setTracksViewChanges(false)}
        />
      ) : (
        <Image
          source={require('src/assets/images/blueMarker.png')}
          style={{
            height: 30,
            width: 30,
            resizeMode: 'contain',
          }}
          onLoadEnd={() => setTracksViewChanges(false)}
        />
      )}
   </View>
    </Marker>
  );
};

export default CustomMarker;
```

Answer (score 1):

this issue to be connected with [react-native-reanimated.](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated)

after some research i found this solution and its worked for me

[react-native-maps-reanimated-issue-patches](https://github.com/l-barbosa/react-native-maps-reanimated-issue/blob/master/patches/react-native-reanimated%2B2.8.0.patch)

See this Examaple

```js
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/ios/LayoutReanimation/REAUIManager.mm b/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/ios/LayoutReanimation/REAUIManager.mm
index 16ed327..a6afa84 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/ios/LayoutReanimation/REAUIManager.mm
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/ios/LayoutReanimation/REAUIManager.mm
@@ -14,6 +14,9 @@
 #if __has_include(<RNScreens/RNSScreen.h>)
 #import <RNScreens/RNSScreen.h>
 #endif
+#if __has_include("AIRMapMarker.h")
+#import "AIRMapMarker.h"
+#endif
 
 @interface RCTUIManager (REA)
 - (void)_manageChildren:(NSNumber *)containerTag
@@ -125,6 +128,9 @@ - (void)_manageChildren:(NSNumber *)containerTag
       if ([toRemoveChild isKindOfClass:[RCTModalHostView class]]
 #if __has_include(<RNScreens/RNSScreen.h>)
           || ([toRemoveChild isKindOfClass:[RNSScreenView class]])
+#endif
+#if __has_include("AIRMapMarker.h")
+          || ([toRemoveChild isKindOfClass:[AIRMapMarker class]])
 #endif
       ) {
         // we don't want layout animations when removing modals or Screens of native-stack since it brings buggy
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this solution. Stuff like this is extremely difficult to fix  without anything to go on